# What's the path for resources under a flavor folder?

Tags: android, unit-testing, integration-testing, picasso, android-espresso

I'm trying to write some integration tests using **Espresso**, and my code is loading images with **Picasso** using

```
picasso.load(path);
```

which underneath calls

```
Uri.parse(path);
```

I would like to provide local resources for these images under

> app -> src -> flavor -> resources

so I can be a good test citizen and not make network calls in my tests.

My Google-Fu isn't so good today, because I couldn't find any information on this so my question is, what is the path for resources under this folder so I can have Picasso load my local resources in a test?

I tried

> file://resources/image_name.jpg

but that doesn't work.

Comment: That's not working, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Put the file into:

```
app/src/main/assets/sample.png
```

And load like so:

```
Picasso.with(this)
    .load("file:///android_asset/sample.png")
    .into(imageView);
```

**EDIT:**

Or put the file into

```
app/src/main/res/raw/sample.png
```

And load like this:

```
Picasso.with(this)
    .load(R.raw.sample)
    .into(imageView);
```